# How do I make an html text input readonly but be able to update with a script?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, razor

I have these inputs that take the values of a  from a  in my table when I click on a row. I want to make it so that the user cannot change the input themselves but want to bring values into them when a user clicks a table row. I will be passing these inputs in as a form. I know that when the input is like this:

that it will not be updated. Is there any other way to do it with an input. Is there a different type of tag I can use that can be passed through a form?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a read-only `<input>`, I'd go with a combination of a display element and a hidden form element.  Something like:

```
<div id="my-display">This is a value</div>
<input id="my-input" name="my-input" type="hidden" />
```

And in the code update both:

```
$('#my-display').text(yourValue);
$('#my-input').val(yourValue);
```

You can style the display to the user however you like and don't have to worry about whether or not it "de-activates" the form input.

---

If you really want it to be an inactive input, you can use the same approach:

```
<input class="my-input" type="text" disabled />
<input class="my-input" type="hidden" name="my-input" />
```

Which may even save you a line of code here, since both can now use `.val()`:

```
$('.my-input').val(yourValue);
```

Comment: Your second solution was what I was going for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try disabled keyword as [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sLexn34f/)

```
<div id="my-display">This is a value</div>
<input id="my-input" name="my-input" type="text" disabled/>
```

You can change the value by javascript as below:

```
document.querySelector('#my-input').value = 'the value you want to enter by javascript';
```